# How to get k8s controller manager's metrics?

Tags: kubernetes, kube-controller-manager

I have deploy a k8s cluster with `kubeadm`, I want to get controller manager's metrics with following command:

```
curl -k https://localhost:10257/metrics
```

but got the following error:

```
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {

  },
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "forbidden: User \"system:anonymous\" cannot get path \"/metrics\"",
  "reason": "Forbidden",
  "details": {

  },
  "code": 403
}
```

So my question is, how to get k8s controller manager's metrics?

Answer (score 0):

This is a forbidden error due to permission issues which need to be authenticated with a valid user. For this,You need to create a service account, then give that service account access permissions to the metrics Path through RBAC, then this will make that service account to get the metrics.

As per this [Role and Cluster Binding doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#role-examples), you need to allow metrics path(replace with /healthz) as below  and give a try.

> ```
> Allow GET and POST requests to the non-resource endpoint /healthz and all subpaths (must be in a ClusterRole bound with a ClusterRoleBinding to be effective):
> rules:
>
>
> - nonResourceURLs: ["/healthz", "/healthz/*"] # '*' in a nonResourceURL is a suffix glob match
>
>
>  verbs: ["get", "post"]
> ```

Answer (score 0):

If your cluster uses RBAC, reading metrics requires authorization via a user, group or ServiceAccount with a ClusterRole that allows accessing /metrics. To get the kubernetes controller manager, scheduler and other control plane components you have to do the authorized user. As per this [Kubernetes System Components Metrics](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/system-metrics/).

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: prometheus
rules:
  - nonResourceURLs:
      - "/metrics"
    verbs:
      - get
```